# Magento MySQL DB Deadlocks

Tags: mysql, magento, innodb, deadlock, mysql-5.1

I am trying to aid a client in resolving MySql DB deadlocks. These deadlocks appear to be causing API calls to take 10-30 seconds. I have retry logic on API calls to attempt at least 3 times. However my applications still fails after 3 API calls, most of the time due to the Deadlocks.

I have a print out of the 'show engine innodb status'. I have improved a few magento queries that seemed to be plaguing this Magento installation. I still have this one that seems to be popping up in the status most of the time. I cleared cache, truncated log tables, and removed sales_flat_quote older than 60 days.

I will point out that this MySql version is 5.1. I am thinking of telling the client that they should upgrade to 5.5, would this solve a majority of the issues?

What I notice about this deadlock is that the locks don't make sense. The 2nd transaction shouldn't have trouble with that index (in my opinion).

*This is Magento Enterprise 1.12.1.*

```
=====================================
140317 14:02:19 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 3 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 126213527, signal count 95958876
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 23717002258, OS waits 75872845
RW-shared spins 28395611, OS waits 6711740; RW-excl spins 47024915, OS waits 2065225
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140317 12:00:01  Cannot truncate table `testcom_testcom_migration`.`catalogsearch_query` by DROP+CREATE
InnoDB: because it is referenced by `testcom_testcom_migration`.`bss_cms_result`
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140317 14:02:07
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 496858972, ACTIVE 1 sec, process no 6717, OS thread id 139831325689600 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 23 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 12 row lock(s), undo log entries 10
MySQL thread id 1260454, query id 109805416 localhost testcom_new updating
DELETE FROM `catalogrule_product_price` WHERE (product_id='12216')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 846908 n bits 1272 index `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_PRODUCT_ID` of table `testcom_testcom_migration`.`catalogrule_product_price` trx id 0 496858972 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 252 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00002fb8; asc   / ;; 1: len 4; hex 001abcde; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 496858674, ACTIVE 8 sec, process no 6717, OS thread id 139831333410560 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
11259 lock struct(s), heap size 1013744, 561072 row lock(s), undo log entries 48
MySQL thread id 1260440, query id 109805651 localhost testcom_new Updating
UPDATE `index_process` SET `status` = 'require_reindex' WHERE (process_id='9')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 846908 n bits 1272 index `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_PRODUCT_ID` of table `testcom_testcom_migration`.`catalogrule_product_price` trx id 0 496858674 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00002df7; asc   - ;; 1: len 4; hex 001abbf7; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00002df7; asc   - ;; 1: len 4; hex 001abbf8; asc     ;;
....
....
....
etc....
```

**Additional Info**

SHOW CREATE TABLE index_process

```
CREATE TABLE `index_process` (
 `process_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Process Id',
 `indexer_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Indexer Code',
 `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending' COMMENT 'Status',
 `started_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Started At',
 `ended_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ended At',
 `mode` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'real_time' COMMENT 'Mode',
 PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE` (`indexer_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Index Process'
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogrule_product_price

```
CREATE TABLE `catalogrule_product_price` (
 `rule_product_price_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rule Product PriceId',
 `rule_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT 'Rule Date',
 `customer_group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Customer Group Id',
 `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Id',
 `rule_price` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Rule Price',
 `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
 `latest_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Latest StartDate',
 `earliest_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Earliest EndDate',
 PRIMARY KEY (`rule_product_price_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATRULE_PRD_PRICE_RULE_DATE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_PRD_ID` (`rule_date`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` (`customer_group_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
 KEY `IDX_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOGRULE_PRODUCT_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CATRULE_PRD_PRICE_CSTR_GROUP_ID_CSTR_GROUP_CSTR_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_CATRULE_PRD_PRICE_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1805881 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='CatalogRule Product Price'
```

Comment: What isolation levels do these two session use ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not all sure what you mean. So I searched for isolation info and found this. https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/20/innodb-isolation-levels/

So I ran this script "SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;"

'REPEATABLE-READ' was returned for both variables.

Comment: Thank for the information, could you also show structures of both tables ? Please login to the database using a client (phpadmin, mysqlworkbench etc.) and run commands: `SHOW CREATE TABLE index_process` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogrule_product_price`, then paste outputs of these commands to the question. My guess is that there is a foreign constraint between these two tables, and this is a cause of "strange" deadlocks.

Comment: I have added the requested information. Nothing appears to be conflicting. So far my guess is that transaction 2 shows update query but this is really the true conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Not the queries, but the transactions(!) do conflict. Transaction 2 holds a shared lock on `catalogrule_product_price`. Transaction 1 tries to update `catalogrule_product_price` and needs an exclusive lock for that. This locks.
Since you removed the lower part of transaction 2 of the logs, we cannot see more details and what finally causes the deadlock. Please provide full logs.

Transaction 2 runs fairly long by the way. It is already active for 8 seconds, and locks for the same amount of time. This is not good for an application. You might want to read the tips on [coping with deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-deadlocks.html), which basically says that one should try to avoid the deadlocks by changing the query executions.

Another tip listed there is to use a lower isolation level, mentioning `READ COMMITTED`, but I assume this does not help here (but you should give it a try!).

You should take a close look at what the long running transaction (and the corresponding script) is doing. Search the code for this update query

```
UPDATE `index_process` SET `status` = 'require_reindex' WHERE (process_id='9')
```

and analyze what the corresponding script does.

Your main problem is that this scripts locks rows (product price rows) for a long time, which are likely widely used inside your application. To circumvent this you might avoid the shared locks it acquires by setting the transaction isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but understand [what it means to set this transaction level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted). This script might use old data then. If you can afford this drawback, this might solve your problem.

**Updating** MySQL will most likely **not solve your problem**. Deadlocks do not depend on the version. (But you might want to update nevertheless, since there were some serious execution improvements from 5.1 to 5.5. concerning the optimizer for example.)

Comment: Sorry, while your information is helpful. It does not help me solve the particular problem at hand. I have already done much of what you asked. However this is not my application. It is Magento, so I am looking for help that is focused around Magento. Hoping someone has found a solution for the same issue. I haven't gone to far into the code yet. I have already fixed one other common deadlock. Magento is just full of them.